# Error with WaitHandle and Thread.Sleep

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I looked around on here for a way to make my script wait a few seconds and found [this article](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Signaling_with_Event_Wait_Handles) which people recommended. I took some of this code and used it in my game to make it wait but it doesn't act as I want it to. I placed it between two Debug.Log lines but it waits for the designated time and then logs both things at once instead of waiting after the first has triggered.

```
static void Waiter(){
    waitHandle.WaitOne ();
}
Debug.Log (choice);

new Thread (Waiter).Start ();   
Thread.Sleep (5000);
waitHandle.Set ();

Debug.Log (enemyChoice);
```

Comment: Can you share the actual code you are using to do this , instead of snippet

Comment: You should never use Thred.Sleap in a Unity game. Go look for unity specific tutorials. you just need a coroutine and `WaitForSecconds`

Answer (score 3):

To wait in Unity, you use coroutine and [`WaitForSeconds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html). You can also use coroutine with [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) or [`Time.time`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html) but the simplest way to do this is to use [`WaitForSeconds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html). Note that if you wait with `Thread.Sleep`, your whole program will freeze. Don't do that because the UI will not be responsive too.

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(doSomethingThenWait());
}

IEnumerator doSomethingThenWait()
{
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Before Waiting");
    //Wait for 2 Seconds
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("After Waiting");
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what the start Coroutine and IEnumerator parts do please

Comment: `StartCoroutine` iscalling the `doSomethingThenWait()` function to start. You can' call it directly like a normal function with `doSomethingThenWait()`. You have to use `StartCoroutine` to call it. `IEnumerator` is the return type of the function that enables you to call it with `StartCoroutine`. You should Google "Unity coroutine tutorial" and learn more about it.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: I tested this code and it isnt working how i would want it to, I have placed the coroutine part inbetween two different debug.log lines hoping that it would show the first, then show "Before waiting", then "after waiting" and then the second debug.log. However what i get is, the first debug.log, "before waiting", the second debug.log - then a 2 second break, and then "after waiting".

How can I get it so that the program waits correctly as i would want?