# Coroutine and waitforseconds not working as planned

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello I've been having trouble with the Coroutine function and wait for seconds. After clicking a button my code should:

- Print Choice,
- Print Before Wait,
- Wait for 2 seconds,
- Print After Wait,
- Print EnemyChoice, and then
- Print the result (Win, draw or loss).

However what i get is:

- Print Choice,
- Print Before wait,
- Print EnemyChoice,
- Print results,
- Wait 2 seconds,
- Print After wait.

How can I get it so that the wait stops the code carrying on for the time correctly.

```
IEnumerator wait(){ // This is the function to call it to wait
    Debug.Log ("Before Wait");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (2);
    Debug.Log ("After Wait");
}

void Update () {

    if (chosen == false) {
        if (choice != "")
            chosen = true;
    }

    if (chosen == true){
        enemyChoice = "";
        int n = rnd.Next(num.Count);
        enemyChoice = choices [n];
        Debug.Log (choice); // Here choice should be printed, then the coroutine started and then enemy choice printed
        StartCoroutine (wait ());
        Debug.Log (enemyChoice);
        chosen = false;
        toDecide = true;
        }


    if (toDecide == true){ // sorry for the clunky way of deciding the result
        if (choice == enemyChoice) {
            Debug.Log ("Draw");
        } else if (choice == "rock" && enemyChoice == "paper") {
            Debug.Log ("Lose");
        } else if (choice == "rock" && enemyChoice == "scissors") {
            Debug.Log ("Win");
        } else if (choice == "paper" && enemyChoice == "rock") {
            Debug.Log ("Win");
        } else if (choice == "paper" && enemyChoice == "scissors") {
            Debug.Log ("Lose");
        } else if (choice == "scissors" && enemyChoice == "paper") {
            Debug.Log ("Win");
        } else if (choice == "scissors" && enemyChoice == "rock") {
            Debug.Log ("Lose");
        } else {
            Debug.Log ("Error");
        }

        toDecide = false;
        choice = "";
        enemyChoice = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: A coroutine does not block execution of `Update` - that's also not the intention of it. You may want to move `Debug.Log(enemyChoice)` inside the coroutine

Comment: Like your last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44232352/error-with-waithandle-and-thread-sleep), do **not** try to make a game with coroutine until you fully understand it. Create a simple project, find coroutine tutorial online then play around with coroutines and see the flow of it. If you don't do this, you will run into many problems. Stackoverflow won't be able to make you fully understand how to use coroutines. That's totally up to you.

Comment: I have found that a lot of the times I was using timing coroutines, I didn't actually need them. If you are creating a situation that you need to perform an action every second or so, just put a counter in Update() and check it each loop. 

If you are worried about making code simultaneous, simply move the code you need to run into a separate monobehaviour and allow it to be toggled. I've never really had to use coroutines once I got my head around this simpler method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar questions have been asked many times before, on StackOverflow and on Unity Answers.

Coroutines do not pause the execution of the function they have been called into. You have to put your logic inside a big coroutine instead :

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine( GameLogic() ) ;
}

IEnumerator GameLogic () {

    while (true )
    {
        if (chosen == false) {
            if (choice != "")
                chosen = true;
        }

        if (chosen == true){
            enemyChoice = "";
            int n = rnd.Next(num.Count);
            enemyChoice = choices [n];
            Debug.Log (choice); // Here choice should be printed, then the coroutine started and then enemy choice printed

            Debug.Log ("Before Wait");
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (2);
            Debug.Log ("After Wait");

            Debug.Log (enemyChoice);
            chosen = false;
            toDecide = true;
        }


        if (toDecide == true){ // sorry for the clunky way of deciding the result
            if (choice == enemyChoice) {
                Debug.Log ("Draw");
            } else if (choice == "rock" && enemyChoice == "paper") {
                Debug.Log ("Lose");
            } else if (choice == "rock" && enemyChoice == "scissors") {
                Debug.Log ("Win");
            } else if (choice == "paper" && enemyChoice == "rock") {
                Debug.Log ("Win");
            } else if (choice == "paper" && enemyChoice == "scissors") {
                Debug.Log ("Lose");
            } else if (choice == "scissors" && enemyChoice == "paper") {
                Debug.Log ("Win");
            } else if (choice == "scissors" && enemyChoice == "rock") {
                Debug.Log ("Lose");
            } else {
                Debug.Log ("Error");
            }

            toDecide = false;
            choice = "";
            enemyChoice = "";
        }

        yield return null ; // To wait one frame
    }
}
```

Comment: So i put all of my relevant code into one big Corountine, do this include any code i havent included (just declaring variables)

Comment: And also what would i do with my Update()

Comment: Consider the block code inside the `while` loop as your initial Update function, so yes, you may have to put all the code you haven't included inside the `while` block code.
I think you can remove the Update function since this big coroutine is now your Update function.

Comment: I did this and when i click play my whole unity just freezes? Wait im an idiot i think i found the error

Comment: You may have forgotten the `yield return null ;` just before the end of your `while` block

Comment: Yeah that was it xD Thank you ill just test now

Answer (score 2):

First you have to understand that `Update` is a method that is called every frame. Again and again.

If your game is hitting 60 frames per second, this means that `Update` will be called 60 times per second (You can check this adding `Debug.Log("Update!");` in `Update()`).

Now, if you want to have some logic that waits for x seconds it should be outside `Update`, because, as we know `Update` will be called again and again, without caring about any `WaitForSeconds`.

Here is a simple example of two methods (well, one is a method and another is a coroutine) and the result of the execution:

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start() 
{
    Method1();
    StartCoroutine(Method2CR());
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update() {
    // I don't want call my methods/Coroutines many times per frame..
}

IEnumerator Wait5Seconds()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);
}

void Method1()
{
    Debug.Log("Method1 before Wait5Seconds: " + Time.time);
    StartCoroutine(Wait5Seconds());
    Debug.Log("Method1 after Wait5Seconds: "+ Time.time);
}

IEnumerator Method2CR()
{
    Debug.Log("Method2CR before Wait5Seconds: "+ Time.time);
    yield return StartCoroutine(Wait5Seconds());
    Debug.Log("Method2CR after Wait5Seconds: " + Time.time);
}
```

and the output is:

```
Method1 before Wait5Seconds: 0
Method1 after Wait5Seconds: 0
Method2CR before Wait5Seconds: 0
Method2CR after Wait5Seconds: 5.010797
```

You can read [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) to get an idea of what is going on behind the scenes on Monobehaviour elements. Look at the `Script Lifecycle Flowchart` picture.